# PHP error when trying to find cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I set a cookie this way

```
$id = 5; //just for clarification
setcookie("NAME", $id, time()+3600*24);
```

And look for it this way

```
$cookie = $_COOKIE["NAME"];
```

I check if this cookie is set (using: `if(isset($cookie)))` and it works perfectly.

The thing is, this code works only if the cookie is set, but if not, I get the following error

```
Notice: Undefined index: NAME in [path], line [line]
```

In some cases the cookie will not be set (naturally). Is there a way I can handle it?

Comment: You should put the `isset()` around `$_COOKIE['NAME']`, not around the `$cookie` variable.

Comment: var_dump($_COOKIE); please post what it prints

Comment: @Caramiriel you are right, I appreciate it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['NAME'])){
  echo "Cookie Is Set";
  // Continue cookie validation without the echo.
}
```

Because you currently are referring to the global `$_COOKIE` and not the individual key

Answer (score 4):

```
$cookie = isset($_COOKIE["NAME"]) ? $_COOKIE["NAME"] : null;
```

and you can continue checking for `isset($cookie)` whenever you use the cookie

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by checking `isset($_COOKIE['NAME'])` before accessing it. Alternatively you can turn off that error message entirely (Not a good idea, it will be on by default on most servers usually). For that see the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting). You would want to turn off E_NOTICE in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check `isset($_COOKIE["NAME"])` or `array_has_key($_COOKIE, "name");` or something like that